# Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

When I try to convert my ggplot2 graphic in R to plotly, it gives the following error message. What does it mean?

(R version: R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)

"Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) :

Here is the full code:

```
library(ggplot2)
flowers<-ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Length)) + geom_point(col="blue")
library(plotly)

set_credentials_file("MyUsername", "Mykey") ## i left out my logins
py <- plotly()
r<-py$ggplotly(flowers)
r$response$url
```

Comment: Hm... on which line do you get the error? Are you sure that the installation worked OK?

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution that I got from the folks at Plotly

"As you know, a number of news sources and the OpenSSL team reported October 14 that version 3 of Secure Sockets Layer (SSLv3) is vulnerable at the protocol level.

At Plotly, we disabled SSLv3 and upgraded to Transport Layer Service (TLS). This requires our R and ggplot2 users to update their Plotly R library. To upgrade, run the following in your R console:

```
library(devtools)  
install_github("ropensci/plotly")
```

"